# Run Spring Boot application with test application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, cypress

I've just installed Cypress to run e2e tests and that requires my Spring Boot app running so it can plug into the browser to run tests.

I already have an `application.properties` file under `test/resources` which creates an H2 memory database populated from a `test/resources/data.sql` to run my unit and integration tests.

I want to start my app using those test resources so I can run Cypress tests with my testing environment, is that poosible?

I tried changing `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` env variable to `test` but it doesn't take my config files under the `test` folder, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

`test/resources/application.properties` is, as far as I understand it, purely for use in (unit/integration/service) tests that live in `test/`.

Try creating an additional `application-test.properties` file in `main/resources`. This should be used when you have the `test` Spring profile activated (although it might be better to choose another name for the profile to avoid confusion).

Comment: I know but I want to avoid code duplication with my data.sql file and some test configuration classes

Comment: rename test/resources/application.properties to test/resources/application-test.properties and make sure during testing you have used the active profile as test